# pam_cracklib.so is not added to my Rocko build when I add PAM support

Tags: yocto, pam

I am trying to add PAM support to my embedded Linux build.   I am using a the Rocko version of the Yocto project.  I added DISTRO_FEATURES_append += " pam" to my build. In my build I see the pam.d folder as expected.  In my /lib/security folder I see many of the expected modules like pam_unix.so and pam_group.so.  What I do NOT see is the pam_cracklib.so module.  I looked at the BB recipe for pam given by the Rocko release and I see that it depends on cracklib and the supplied cracklib recipe is run.
I must be missing something basic.  Why do I not see the pam_cracklib.so module available?  I also verified it is not in some other folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libpam recipe uses dynamic packaging to put each plugin into its own package. You need to add the correct package into your image: it should be `pam-plugin-cracklib-<baselib>` -- check e.g. the *$WORKDIR/packages-split/* directory to see what packages were built.

Comment: Yes this was the source.  What confused me was it was listed here in the recipe: 
 RDEPENDS_${PN}-xtests but not here: RDEPENDS_${PN}-runtime.  Once I added it to the runtime list it was added to my build.